# itext pdf help in fx20

Tags: c#, itext

Why wouldn't the following work?

```
phrase.AddAll(new ICollection<Chunk>[] { noteChunk, noteAttributeChunk });
```

> Error  8   Cannot implicitly convert type 'iTextSharp.text.Chunk' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'.

Just curious,

rod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to a generic parameter to `ICollection` such as `ICollection<Chunk>`, but the problem is that `ICollection` is an interface and not a class. You should probably do this instead:

```
phrase.AddAll(new Chunk[] { noteChunk, noteAttributeChunk });
```